# Increase number of decimal places in SharePoint calculated column while list exceeds the list view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, list-view-threshold

I am facing an issue while I need to increase number of decimal places of list calculative column. I need it in SharePoint online - unfortunately the list contains more than 40K records (and increasing). As the list contains huge records, I get the error message **"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."** -  when I go to change the decimal places from 2 to 3 and save the column edit option.

Obviously - the threshold issue is preventing me to modify the column settings but getting no point to do this. For List views I have optimized column with indices and filter - so I can manage views as my needs. for this modification of column settings getting no clue.

Appreciate in advance!

Comment: Just a note: I get the error message in the classic SharePoint experience, currently I have no option to move to modern.

Comment: This link didn't hellp me really: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/addchange-calculated-field-formula-for-a-list-more/1f48707c-d39b-44e5-af23-0ebe0a8f49b2

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an index to the column as you have exceeded the [List View Threshold](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/items-exceeds-list-view-threshold) and been blocked. In SharePoint Online, you can manually add an index to a list of any size. Please refer to these articles for more information: [Add an index to a SharePoint column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Thanks Jerry- Actually I have so many columns - already the number of index columns exceeded (20 in SPO) and that part has been taken care of. Its not helping me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All - Using CSOM C#) application came across a solution:

```
    private static void UpdateCalculativeColumnDecimal(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        string listName = "ListName";
        string fieldName = "columnName"; //calculated column
        string newValue = "2";           //--Decimal place

        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

        try
        {
            // fetch the fields from this list
            FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
            clientContext.Load(fields);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Field field = fields.GetByTitle(fieldName);
            clientContext.Load(field);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(field.SchemaXml);
            XmlNode fieldNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Field");
            XmlAttribute decimalAttribute = fieldNode.Attributes["Decimals"];
            if (decimalAttribute == null)
            {
                decimalAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("Decimals");
                fieldNode.Attributes.Append(decimalAttribute);
            }

            decimalAttribute.Value = newValue;
            field.SchemaXml = doc.OuterXml;
            field.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Note: ClientContext has been passed to the method as SP site connection context.